# How do I loop a check for string in a document in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, loops, button

I'm trying to make a code that will search for a specific text, and if it is found it will click a button. It needs to check for the string continuously, however I am struggling to find a way for that to happen. I'm a complete newb to coding, so any help is appreciated! :)

```
var findMe = [
    //Test
    'Hello!',
];

function findText() {
    var text = document.querySelector('div[id=BtnText]');

    for (var i = 0; i < findMe.length; i++) {
        if (BtnText.match(findMe[i])) {
            var btnDo = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"][value="Click!"]');
            if (btnDo) {
                btnDo.click();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly is the error you get?

Comment: Are you trying to search the window for the words in the array ?

Comment: no particular error, it's just when the text does come up the button isn't clicked. I know the button clicking script is fine, I'm just thinking i've messed up somewhere in the function.

Comment: The variable `text` would be a boolean, but you're not using it anywhere, and what is `BtnText` ?

Comment: and yes, i'm looking through the window for any of the words in the array, which is just 'Hello!' at the moment.

Comment: You're sure it should'nt be more like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vzu6x/2/) ???

Answer (score 1):

Just editing your code a little bit.

I am assuming you have HTML like this?

```
<div id="BtnText">Hello!</div><input type="submit" value="Click!">
```

You will to change your code to this

```
var findMe = [
    //Test
    'Hello!',
];

function findText() {
    var div = document.querySelector('div[id=BtnText]');

    for (var i = 0; i < findMe.length; i++) {
        if (div.innerText.indexOf(findMe[i]) !== -1) {               
            var btnDo = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"][value="Click!"]');
            if (btnDo) {
                if (typeof btnDo.onclick == "function") {
                    btnDo.onclick.apply(elem);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you want to check continuously. I recommend using setInterval.

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
   var textFound = findText();
   if(textFound) {
       clearInterval(interval);
   }
},50);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression:

```
(new RegExp('word')).test(str)

(new RegExp(/word/)).test(str)
```

indexOf:

```
str.indexOf('word') !== -1
```

search()
searches a string for a specified value, or regular expression, and returns the position of the match.

```
var n=str.search("word");
```

or

```
 var n-str.search(/word/);
    if(n>0)
    {}
```

with window.find()

```
if (window.find("word", true)){}
//code
while(window.find("word",true){
//code
}
```

Comment: And window.find does this in the global scope with one single line without any regex ?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to perform the check continously?
You should get another approach... Or your script will be blocked by Chrome, for example, if it makes the page non responsible. You can go for a timeout, as Taylor Hakes suggested... Or just call your findText function attached to the onChange event on the div.